# How to create temporary table and JOIN with node table in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have been working in a Drupal 7 web application.

Today I have tried to create a temporary table in my custom module using db_query_temporary function as follows:

```
$result = db_query_temporary("select * from {node}");
```

but $result gives "db_temporary_0".
I need to JOIN a temporary table created from a complex query with {node} table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`db_query_temporary()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query_temporary/7.x) creates a temporary table and returns the table's name, so `db_temporary_0` seems perfectly reasonable.  You will use that result in your [`db_select()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x) to join to whatever else you need:

```
 // obviously you wouldn't want something this simple....
 $tmp_tbl = db_query_temporary("SELECT * FROM {node}");
 $query = db_select('node', 'n');
 $query->join($tmp_tbl, 't', n.nid = t.nid'); //JOIN with node
```